# trying to make sense of a bash script

Tags: bash, chef-infra

The script is supposed to distribute keys from an ossec server to it's clients

```
cat /usr/local/bin/dist-ossec-keys.sh
#!/bin/sh
#

for host in chef-production2-doctor-simulator01
do
  echo "host is $host"
  key=`mktemp`
  grep $host /var/ossec/etc/client.keys > $key
  echo "key is $key"
  scp -i /var/ossec/.ssh/id_rsa -B -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $key ossecd@$host:/var/ossec/etc/client.keys >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
  rm $key
  ech "done" 
done
```

I ran the script line by line and it's output is

```
host is chef-production2-doctor-simulator01
key is /tmp/tmp.fAZqvNkJ9f
```

The bash script is created from [this](https://github.com/jtimberman/ossec-cookbook/blob/master/templates/default/dist-ossec-keys.sh.erb) template

```
cat /var/ossec/etc/client.keys
001 #*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#197.221.226 7196c76c568258e2ad836f8e1aa37e0758dee969f560ceb59be76879c3f3412d
002 test-agent 10.128.0.9 e2c9b117f26a202598007dcb4ec64e01f18000f9d820f6b3508a95e5313e6537
```

what is it supposed to do ?
why is it not working?

Comment: Why don't you distribute the keys using a Chef cookbook? Not sure, how far you're with chef, but IMHO that's exactly when life is easier when having an infrastructure managed through Chef.

Comment: @StephenKing that's what i'm trying to do , it's not working so i'm trying to debug it . basically this script runs via a chef client .

Comment: You kick of that script, which logins to other nodes via SSH? If these other nodes also run chef, it would be amazingly easy and clean (using a cookbook that runs _there_).

Comment: i don't understand you . 1. The script is supposed to be ran by the server and not the client. the chef software is simply a wrapper to run this script evantually.

Comment: Why do think it isn't working? You didn't mention any kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the `scp -i /var/ossec/...` line

My poor linux knowledge failed to notice the 
`>/dev/null 2>/dev/null`

removing that revealed the real error (which was `Permission denied (publickey)`)